# Excel VBA changing time/day format on columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am having to change the Day/Time format for over 9000 provider records. I am new at vba and am not sure what way to go about it, since there are over 100 varieties of provider office hours.

I thought about using a button that would create a new column that would populate the correct information, but I am not sure that is the right path. I thought about doing `If` statements but I know that would be over 100 `If` statements due to the variety of office hours.

The current day/time format the is generated in Excel is:

```
M 8:30 AM-5:30 PM 
T 8:30 AM-5:30 PM 
W 8:30 AM-5:30 PM 
R 8:30 AM-5:30 PM 
F 8:30 AM-5:30 PM
```

I need to turn that into `M-F 8:30 AM-5:30 PM`

Here is another example

```
M 7:30 AM-11:00 PM
T 7:30 AM-11:00 PM
W 7:30 AM-11:00 PM
R 7:30 AM-11:00 PM
F 7:30 AM-11:00 PM
S 8:00 AM-9:00 PM
```

Desired end result:

```
M-F 7:30 AM - 11:00 PM; SA 8:00 AM - 9:00 PM
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've tagged the question with VBA, so please, post the code you have tried, where are you stuck. We do not code for free here, but we help to resolve **specific** coding questions.

Answer (score 0):

In case an Excel solution might work for you, maybe you can adapt this your needs:

[image]

**NOTE**: For this formula to work:

1. Your data must start at row 2 or lower, but not on row 1 in any case or formula won't work properly.
2. Data must be sorted like the one you posted (all same times grouped together, or it won't work)

And the formula:    `=IF(IF(TRIM(MID(A2;3;99))=TRIM(MID(A1;3;99));"";ROW())="";"";LEFT(INDEX($A:$A;IF(TRIM(MID(A2;3;99))=TRIM(MID(A1;3;99));"";ROW()));1)&"-"&LEFT(INDEX($A:$A;IF(TRIM(MID(A2;3;99))=TRIM(MID(A1;3;99));"";ROW())+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12;"*"&TRIM(MID(A2;3;99))&"*")-1);1)&" "&TRIM(MID(A2;3;99)))`

As you may noticed in the image, last result does not fit your needs (you posted `SA 8:00 AM - 9:00 PM` and my formula gets `S-S 8:00 AM-9:00 PM` because, to be honest, I have no idea where that `A` comes from.

Because the complexity of the formula, I've uploaded the file to my Gdrive, and in the file you'll find 2 sheets: one with the formula in just 1 cell, and one with the formula in several columns, emulatin a step by step resolution, in case you might be interested in checking the idea behind it.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pmrpPqMWwtFtdzt3-lQoK5npd_JeQs0m

Try to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Step
1   Replace - with space (Column C with formula =SUBSTITUTE(B6,"-"," "))
2   Extract Day of Week (Column D with Formula =TIMEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C6," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C6))),(1)*LEN(C6)+1,LEN(C6)))&" "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C6," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C6))),(2)*LEN(C6)+1,LEN(C6))))
3   Extract Time Start(Column E with formula =TIMEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C25," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C25))),(1)*LEN(C25)+1,LEN(C25)))&" "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C25," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C25))),(2)*LEN(C25)+1,LEN(C25))))
4   Extract Time End (Column f with formula =TIMEVALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C25," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C25))),(3)*LEN(C25)+1,LEN(C25)))&" "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C25," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C25))),(4)*LEN(C25)+1,LEN(C25))))
5   Determine if Saturday is included(D32 with formula =IF(COUNTIF(D25:D30,"S"),"Yes","No"))
6   Get Min Time Start (E32 with formula =MIN(E25:E29))
7   Get Max Time End (F32 with formula =MAX(F25:F29))
9   Get final result (B34 with Formula =IF(D32="No",("M-F "&TEXT(E32,"hh:mm AM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(F32,"hh:mm AM/PM")),("M-F "&TEXT(E32,"hh:mm AM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(F32,"hh:mm AM/PM")&(",SA "&TEXT(VLOOKUP("S",D25:F30,2,FALSE),"hh:mm AM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(VLOOKUP("S",D25:F30,3,FALSE),"hh:mm AM/PM")))))
ASSUMPTIONS
1   All original text is formatted the same
2   You are looking for the earliest start time in the array
3   you are looking for the latest end time in the array

NOTES
1   These are the steps in excel. You can copy them over to VBA and put them in a loop if you choose
2   "The formulas are complex, but flexable and could be used as templates should your original Data Change."
3   You can combine the various formulas to create a single extract, but they will get rather hard to read
4   Personally, I would do this in excel So I could review the results (and look for non conforming patterns) so I could adjust as necessary.
5   Once I had validated my data I would Copy and paste the results.
6   This is my first time answering a question on this forum so I hope this is germane.

[XLSX Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG9Ue.png)
I would attach an the spreadsheet but I don't see a way. It may not be allowed on the forum.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should edit your question and use some markdowns to make it readable. Check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help